# Regex: find email address when not wrapped in HTML <a> tag

Tags: html, regex

Given a text with email addresses I would like to match all the ones that are not wrapped inside an "a" tag. And I can only do it with a regex.

THIS MATCH:

```
something@something.else
```

THIS DOES NOT MATCH:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using? What is the e-mail format? What have you already tried?

Comment: [This is worth a read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) if you're going to match email addresses with a regex.

Comment: At the moment I use http://regexr.com/ for testing. I managed to find all the content wrapped in "a" tags by: <a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a> but I haven't find any way to perform the lookahead for @ symbols (format of the email is not important for my case, finding the @ symbol is sufficient). I have this not-working version: (?!<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>).*@.*

Comment: Is this regex for JS, PHP, Python...?

Comment: For the moment any implementation will do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when... / Except between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics: `/<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>[\W\w]*?<\/a>|([a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)/i`

You'll get every link and every text email, but only the text email will be grouped. Not sure if that's what you wanted, but I think that's the only way you'll be able to do it with a single regex.

Comment: Of course, you'd finesse the email recognition and link recognition, but that all depends on how far you want to go.